# Notify js validation not working

Tags: javascript, php

I have this javascript to validate if the data is already inserted on the database but it seems like its not working. what would be the problem?

```
var a = $("#EngagementID").val();
var b = $("#delete").val();

$('#save').on('click', function(e) {


    if ($("#EmployeeNo").val() !== "") {
        $.notify("You have successfully created a plotting.", "success");
    } else  {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you included notify ?

Answer (score 0):

well if you include the library it should work

```js
$.notify("You have successfully created a plotting.", "success");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/notifyjs/notifyjs/master/dist/notify.js"></script>
```